# Bluetooth Signal strength tizen wearables

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

Is it possible to get the signal strength for the devices found using the web API?

I can't find anything on https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/bluetooth.html#BluetoothClassDeviceService

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I could understand, there's no API support for getting bluetooth signal strength in web till now.
I found that System Information API supports only for wifi signal strength providing SystemInfoWifiNetwork interface not for bluetooth signal strength.

Please go through [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/system-information-api-guide#properties) for more details.